# .htaccess deny some file access for certain IP

Tags: file, .htaccess, ip

I have to deny the access just three php files on a server for a specific IP range, which way should I choose? Are these examples correct?

```
<FilesMatch "\register.php|\login.php|\admincp\index.php|\modcp\index.php">
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from x.x.x.x
</FilesMatch>
```

or

```
<Files "\register.php|\login.php|\admincp\index.php|\modcp\index.php">
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from x.x.x.x
</Files>
```

Thanx for help

Comment: Whats the IP range you are trying to block?

Comment: Russian IP address, for preventing spam and hacking attempts... generated from here: http://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker

Comment: Well this site practically generate the .htaccess for you. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: That's right, it generate the code for .htaccess, but it blocks the entire site, I'd like to block just the php pages listed above, and I'd like to know if the "FilesMatch" and "Files" directives are correct.

Comment: Just change the header to `<Files "\register.php|\login.php|\admincp\index.php|\modcp\index.php">` and the footer too.

Comment: Well.. I tested it with my public IP but it don't work, even if I omit the "\" at the beginning